# How to get started writing SIP / VoIP based software

Tags: sip, voip, rtp, stun

I need to add some SIP based functionality to my company's Windows based software, allowing the user to call extensions and receive calls from extensions registered with a SIP server.  Essentially I'll be creating a simple soft-phone.  The software might be running on separate networks, so NAT, firewalls and STUN servers are considerations.

I'm wondering if others have done this sort of thing and if so do you have any recommendations on how to get started.

Should I write my own SIP stack from scratch?

Should I consider using OPAL?  It looks ideal, but they only list a single company that they know of using their library, which concerns me.

Should I consider other 3rd party libraries?

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid to write your own implementation because this voip is a huge and complex topic.  I would also not recommend OPAL (that is already outdated).
Just search for "SIP SDK" and you will see a lot of ready to use working solutions then just choose whichever seems better for your needs.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  One issue is cost.  OPAL is free to use, which is a huge benefit.  When I search for "SIP SDK" I get plenty of results, but I don't see any other open source options.  If OPAL does a good job and I have access to the source code then the fact that it's free is a huge factor.  Two questions if you don't mind 1) Can you give more detail about why OPAL is outdated?   2) Do you know of any other cheap or free alternatives to OPAL?  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Opal has been around for years - and the code has been provided to various commercial users.
The code has been tested in many harsh environments.

Good software is like wine - it matures with age. Opal has matured well.

The library is extreme C++ - I hope you know C++ well.

Use Opal - cause when they ask for h.323, it will be easy.

The code has been tested on many compilers - (win, gcc, mac) and each compiler can be regarded
as a new pair of eyes, or another CPP quality check system.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.opensips.org/ is a good choice in working for a server side implementation.
If you are to make a SIP client, try searching for webphones.Things with javascripts are cool.

here is a list:
http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Open+Source+VOIP+Software